# Hide a div tag if the next ul's li's are all displayed none

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML with `div`s and next sibling `ul`s like this:

```html
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to make the `div` with class `title` `display: none` if next `ul`'s `li`'s are all `display: none`?

Comment: with javascript code - though upcoming CSS can do it too

Comment: @JaromandaX - Oooh, what's the upcoming thing?

Comment: well, @T.J.Crowder - after reading the actual code, maybe not applicable in this case ... but upcoming (actually exists everywhere except firefox - it can be enabled though) is `:has` ... perhaps something like `div+ul:has(li.visible)` i.e. the code in the question would have to use class instead of style, but ...

Comment: @Jaromanda , i would appreciate if you share js solution for that!

Comment: @Tod - i don't HAVE a JS solution, because I don't know WHY or HOW the li's get display:none

Comment: @JaromandaX - Ah, thanks. I did know about `:has`, but I don't think we can do the visible check without using a class to hide the `li` elements (but that would probably be a better thing to do anyway). :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - thanks for editing.

Comment: @JaromandaX - so, there must be a class added to `<li>`s?

Comment: @Tod no, only if you want the CSS only solution

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - actually, has won't help, since the UL is a sibling not a child - my bad

Comment: @JaromandaX - :-) I think we'd be okay on that, but we'd need to nest `:has` like this: `.title:has(+ ul:has(> li:not(.hidden)))` and you're not allowed to do that. :-(

Comment: I know, after looking at the code more closely I realised `:has` will not help @T.J.Crowder - oh well :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - I added an example with `:has` to my answer -- but we have to change the structure. :-| Thanks for pointing it out, it was both educational (I didn't know you could include relations like `:has(+ p)` and such) and interesting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to be honest I didn't know if that was possible either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, today's CSS can't do that (see below for *tomorrow's* CSS), but with JavaScript you can loop through the `.title` elements and see if their next element is a `ul` and all of its child elements are `display: none`, and set the title element to `display: none` if so:

```js
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(".title")) {
    if (element.nextElementSibling.tagName === "UL" &&
        [...element.nextElementSibling.children].every(
           (child) => getComputedStyle(child).display === "none"
        )) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <div class="title">Should Show</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title">Should Hide</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title">Should Show</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You might factor out at least the `every` calback (and possibly the whole check):

```js
const isDisplayNone = (element) => getComputedStyle(element).display === "none";
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(".title")) {
    if (element.nextElementSibling.tagName === "UL" &&
        [...element.nextElementSibling.children].every(isDisplayNone)
       ) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <div class="title">Should Show</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title">Should Hide</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li style="display: none;">2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title">Should Show</div>
    <ul>
        <li style="display: none;">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li style="display: none;">3</li>
        <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

With **tomorrow's** CSS, we can do it **if** we change the structure slightly to add a wrapper `div` and we hide the `li` elements with a class rather than inline styling (which is almost always best anyway):

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.container .title {
    display: none;
}
.container:has(li:not(.hidden)) .title {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Only works on cutting-edge browsers!!</strong></p>
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Should Show</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="hidden">1</li>
            <li class="hidden">2</li>
            <li class="hidden">3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Should Hide</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="hidden">1</li>
            <li class="hidden">2</li>
            <li class="hidden">3</li>
            <li class="hidden">4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Should Show</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="hidden">1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li class="hidden">3</li>
            <li class="hidden">4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will only work on **cutting-edge** browsers such as Chrome v105 and higher (not even Chrome v104 has it). More about `:has` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#specifications) and [in the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational).

Comment: Thanks for solutions , a minor note  - i have `div`s next to each of`li`s tags like this -  `<li class="hidden">1</li><div id="modal"></div><li class="hidden">2</li><div id="modal"></div>`  and so on, so how to select only `li`'s here  `...element.nextElementSibling.children` ?

Comment: @Tod - You can't do that in a `ul` (or `ol`), they cannot directly contain `div` elements, so the markup is invalid and the browser will "correct" it for you. The *way* the corrects it is not specified behavior and may vary from browser to browser. Either put those `div` elements *inside* the `li` elements, or make them `li` elements (perhaps with a class differentiating them from the others). In the latter case, you'll need to skip those in the check in the code.

Comment: that is very true, thanks a lot! you saved my time, good day to you!

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowders "tomorrow" CSS using `:has` does not require changing the layout - only replacing inline style with a class (as in his answer) - but that's all that needs to change

Note: this works in Chrome and Edge (not sure about Safari) - in Firefox this does not work even with the `:has` config flag enabled - Firefox doesn't like the sibling selector (i.e. `+`) in `:has`

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.title:not(:has(+ul>:not(li.hidden))) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="someid" class="someclass">
  <div class="title">Should Show</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden">1</li>
    <li class="hidden">2</li>
    <li class="hidden">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="title">Should Hide</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden">1</li>
    <li class="hidden">2</li>
    <li class="hidden">3</li>
    <li class="hidden">4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="title">Should Show</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="hidden">3</li>
    <li class="hidden">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```